Access to XMLHttpRequest been blocked by CORS policy: PyGeoAPI
I am trying to create a web page to display a layer that is published through PygeoAPI, as OGC API Features. I have created a web app using the Open Layers quickstart page. I have set "cors: true" in pygeoapi Config.yml file. Still I am getting this error :
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5050/collections/GasPipelines?f=json' from origin 'http://localhost:5175' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
